# Can you run Samba on Snow Leopard workstations?

Tags: macos, smb

it appears that Samba functionality is restricted to the server edition of OS X 10.6 - is there a workaround or third-party solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File sharing is available on the client under System Preferences>Sharing>File Sharing.

You can then select what to share. Once you've done that click the options button. And select the third option shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: ie samba is part of standard Snow Leopard not just the server.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking this functionality to configure SMB shares is new to SL? I certainly haven't bothered to look behind the File Sharing option since the days of Tiger. Many thanks for posting :-)

Comment: It's been around since tiger, but leopard/sl gave you better sharing options.